# Handling sometime existing elements with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape a forum, specifically grabbing if an entry has been edited. This info is saved into a div that does not always appear in other entries. The goal is to either append N/A or the value of the edit date, depending on its existence. Here is an HTML snippet of the page:

```html
<div class="message-content">
    ...
</div>

<div class="message-content">
    ...
    <div class="message-lastEdit">      
        Last edited: <time class="u-dt" data-date-string="Sep 4, 2023">Sep 4, 2023</time>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="message-content">
    ...
</div>
```

Whenever I search for the lastedit div, it only returns the dates of the existing edits, I need a way to differentiate whether this div exists or not when scraping the entries.

After grabbing this info and putting it into a container, it should look something like:

> {'edits': ['N/A', 'Sep 4, 2023', 'N/A']}

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element exist and after that, get the text:

```
try:
    web_element = driver.find_element(by.CLASS_NAME, "message-lastEdit")
    text = web_element.getText()
except Exception:
    web_element = False
    text = False
```